# Generating Disk Method Formula with Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, volume

*This specific case involves solids of revolution about the $x$-axis

I've just started reading on solids of revolution, so forgive me if this is trivial. I'm wondering if this is a valid derivation of the formula used in the disk method.

Supposing we have some function $f(x)$ which we desire to rotate about the $x$-axis between bounds $x_1$ and $x_2$, then per the mean value theorem of integrals, there exists some value for $f(x)$ which we can use to construct a single cylinder of identical volume to the solid of revolution.

Now let's look at the formula for a cylinder:

$$V_C=\pi r^2h$$

Clearly height $h$ is the distance between our lower and upper bounds, which we'll denote $x_1$ and $x_2$, respectively. Thus:

$$V_C=\pi r^2(x_2-x_1)$$

Let's rewrite $\pi r^2$ as base $b$.

$$V_C=b(x_2-x_1)$$

Finally, let's denote the average base area per the mean value theorem as $\bar{b}$. Note that $r^2$ at any point $x$ is given by $f^2(x)$, thus:

$$\bar{b}=\frac{\pi}{x_2-x_1}\int_{x_1}^{x_2}f^2(x)dx$$

Substituting $\bar{b}$ for $b$:

$$V_C=\frac{\pi}{x_2-x_1}\int_{x_1}^{x_2}f^2(x)dx\; *\;(x_2-x_1)$$

Cancelling $(x_2-x_1)$:

$$V_C=\pi\int_{x_1}^{x_2}f^2(x)dx$$

Which is the formula used for the disk method.

Is this a valid approach, and if so, can I improve my explanation in any way?